# Is it possible to synchronously call Signalr server side method from javascript client?

Tags: c#, javascript, signalr

I'd like to call a server hub method from javascript and have the javascript code block until the server side method has returned (some data) - is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to make the SignalR JS client block for hub method invocations.

The only option is to use the [jQuery promise](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) which is returned immediately by SignalR after it starts invoking the hub method. The `then`, `done`, `fail`, etc... methods allow you to add handlers that run after the hub invocation has completed.

You can learn more by reading the [SignalR Hubs API Guide for the JS client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callserver).